# Div tags render as nested when they should be side by side

Tags: html, nested

I am trying to setup a system of nested DIV tags and I get a strange problem. When loaded in the browser (Tested in Safari, Chrome & FF on OS X) the two innermost divs are rendered inside one another.

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m48wG/

The DIVs in question are the lightest gray ones, with the class "l4". In the sourcecode they look like this:

```
<div class="box box-horizontal l4" style="width:100px;height:100px;"></dix>
<div class="box box-horizontal l4" style="width:100px;height:100px;margin-left:3px;"></dix>
```

But inspecting the elements in the browser inspectors gives this:

```
<div class="box box-horizontal l4" style="width:100px;height:100px;">
   <div class="box box-horizontal l4" style="width:100px;height:100px;margin-left:3px;"></dix>
</dix>
```

Any ideas what is causing this and how it can be fixed?

Thanks

EDIT:
HAHA.. Sorry, my bad! Thank you guys, I totally didn't see that one.. Might need to go see an eyedoctor ;)

Comment: your closing tag says `</dix>` instead of `</div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct `</dix>` to `</div>` and you should be fine

In case you're not seeing it right away, change

`<div class="box box-horizontal l4" style="width:100px;height:100px;"></dix>`

to

`<div class="box box-horizontal l4" style="width:100px;height:100px;"></div>`

and with the other incorrect div as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
<body>
<h1>Jeg er test</h1>
<div class="row l1">
  <div class="box box-horizontal l2" style="width:200px;height:200px;"></div>
  <div class="box box-horizontal box-auto l2" style="margin-left:3px;">
   <div class="box box-vertical l3" style="width:200px;height:100px;"></div>
   <div class="box box-vertical box-auto l3" style="margin-top:3px;">
     <div class="box box-horizontal l4" style="width:100px;height:100px;"> </div>
     <div class="box box-horizontal l4" style="width:100px;height:100px;margin-left:3px;"> </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's just a typo in your closing tags.  `</dix>` should be `</div>`